# How to iterate through files using pathlib.glob() when files share very similar names

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

`My Directory` looks like this:

```
P1_AAA_NOT_SAMPLE.csv
P1_AAA_SAMPLE.csv
P1_BBB_NOT_SAMPLE.csv
P1_BBB_SAMPLE.csv
P1_CCC_NOT_SAMPLE.csv
P1_CCC_SAMPLE.csv

P2_AAA_NOT_SAMPLE.csv
P2_AAA_SAMPLE.csv
P2_BBB_NOT_SAMPLE.csv
P2_BBB_SAMPLE.csv
P2_CCC_NOT_SAMPLE.csv
P2_CCC_SAMPLE.csv
```

How do I iterate through files in this directory using `pathlib.glob()` if I want to capture only the SAMPLE files (ie. I don't want the NOT_SAMPLE files).

My code looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\My Directory'

for fle in Path(file_path).glob('P*_*_SAMPLE.csv'):
    # do something with each SAMPLE file
```

But this code will also capture both SAMPLE files and NOT_SAMPLE files. Is there a way to adjust the wildcards or `glob()` part to only capture SAMPLE files, preferably using `pathlib`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is a `if "NOT" in fle` not sufficient?

Comment: Thanks. When I put an `if` statement after the `for` loop, I can't figure out what should follow after the `not in`, ie. `if not in ...`. Do you know what I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter in a generator expression (or a list comprehension), like this:

```
for fle in (p for p in Path(file_path).glob('P*_*_SAMPLE.csv') if 'NOT_SAMPLE' not in str(p)):
```

or build a list before:

```
valid_paths = [p for p in Path(file_path).glob('P*_*_SAMPLE.csv') if 'NOT_SAMPLE' not in str(p)]

for fle in valid_paths:
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting this error `TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable`. Any way I could fix this?

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to test if the string is in `str(p)`, not in the Path object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, if ‘not’ in file name: do something.

after your for loop,

```
for fle in Path(file_path).glob('P*_*_SAMPLE.csv'):
    if 'NOT' not in str(file):
        #do something
```

Comment: Thanks. When I put an `if` statement after the `for` loop, I can't figure out what should follow after the `not in`, ie. `if not in ...`. Do you know what I can try?

Comment: after your for loop,    for fle in Path(file_path).glob('P*_*_SAMPLE.csv'):

Comment: Yeah I was thinking putting the `if` statement after the for loop too but can't figure out what should be after the `if not in ...`, ie. what should `...` be?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but its still capturing both SAMPLE files and NOT_SAMPLE files. I think it's because the `'NOT'` in `if 'NOT' is not file:` is saying the **entire** file name has to be 'NOT' rather than part of the file name. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: I managed to fix this. The code should be `if 'NOT' not in str(fle):` and this works